# How to enable Vagrant's 'verbose' mode?

Tags: vagrant

I'm using Vagrant in a Windows 7 box, and I'm having trouble with the ssh client. I'd like to know how can I make Vagrant 'verbose' (as in report more than a user friendly message) and if it is possible to change the log level.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

For every command in vagrant you can add the `--debug` flag.

You can also set the `VAGRANT_LOG` env variable instead.

For example:

```
$ VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant up
```

or:

```
$ set VAGRANT_LOG=info
$ vagrant up
```

Read more about it at [Vagrant Documentation page](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/other/debugging.html).